# Unable to load WordPress local site after changing WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)

Tags: site-url, home-url

I have setup WordPress in my local machine and worked fine. I have accidentally changed WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). Now I am unable to access the local site. How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: exact same problem; did you get a 502 index error as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) manually and access the local site again. What I did was add following code segments to following files.

1. wp-config.php

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','http://www.local.abc.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.local.abc.com');
   ```
2. Functions.php

I have added following code just after opening of

```
   update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.local.abc.com' );
   update_option('home', 'http://www.local.abc.com' );
```

After that I have refresh site and it worked fine.

Comment: this did not work for me at all. it returns a 502 gateway error if i try to access my site at index