# Can't access wordpress mgt dashboard until propogation finished?

Tags: login, urls, dashboard

So recently i changed the URL on wordpress and got the white blank page error (which i haven't fixed yet despite following the below link). Is it normal that until propagation finishes i won't be able to access the wordpress dashboard?

Also i am new to this stuff so i don't understand and it feels impossible to try and get help... Can you help because this is frustrating.

[Unable to load WordPress local site after changing WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265199/unable-to-load-wordpress-local-site-after-changing-wordpress-address-url-and-s)

Comment: Did you change the URL of a site hosted locally on your computer? Or a site on the web? What change did you make to the URL? Did you change the domain name? How are you attempting to access the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after changing site URL, you will not be able to access the Dashboard until after propagation.

You can set the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants to an accessible URL ([source](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php)).

You can also adjust your machine's `hosts` file to point the domain set in settings to the server. This will work only for your machine, and give you access until the propagation completes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Caleb. I found it quite strange that it wouldn`t be accessible. After all i am trying to access the host server. Why wouldn`t that be accessible just because the site hasn`t propagated to the web.

Comment: Because WordPress performs redirecting internally as a security measure and better experience. Imagine the same site being available at three or four different URLs. 